# Vertical line gap in rows where I have adjusted the row height

Tags: tables, height

I am making a table where I need to adjust the row height.  After adjusting the row height, the vertical lines on my second column do not extend to the correct height (they leave a gap).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}
\Large\centering \textbf{APPROVALS} \\
\normalsize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|p{3.5in}|}
\hline\rowcolor{Gray}
 & \centering SIGNATURE \tabularnewline 
\hline
Document Owner \\  NAME 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c||}{ } \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
 Reviewer \\ Someone 1 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
Reviewer \\ Someone 2 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
Approved: \\ NAME 4 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with line gaps]

Comment: All `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ }` can simply be omitted, by the way.

Comment: Yeah... I added it based on another discussion...  Since it didn't work, but didn't change anything I thought I'd keep it so that no one would suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gaps are because you finished the rows early

```
Document Owner \\
```

has no second cell, so does not get the vertical rules in that cell use

```
Document Owner & \\
```

Comment: I see!  But now I want to fill the cells as they appear in the image.

Answer (score 1):

David pushed me in the right direction.  The following code makes the table I want.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}
\Large\centering \textbf{APPROVALS} \\
\normalsize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|p{3.5in}|}
\hline\rowcolor{Gray}
 \multicolumn{1}{|c}{ }& \centering SIGNATURE \tabularnewline 
\hline
Document Owner1 & \tabularnewline
 NAME 1         & \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
 Reviewer   & \tabularnewline
  Someone 1 &  \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
  Reviewer   &  \tabularnewline
   Someone 2 & \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
 Approved:  &  \tabularnewline
  NAME 4    &  \tabularnewline[15pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]